# How can I change the loss function when the shape of my data changes?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, tensorflow

Since my data is too large, I use `pd.read_csv('',chunksize=)`. I am using `categorical_crossentropy` as my loss function, however, on the last chunk, I have just one target. So I get the error:

> You are passing a target array of shape (2110, 1) while using as loss
>   categorical_crossentropy.

Now I know I can use `binary_crossentropy.`So this is what I did:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data, train_labels, shuffle=True, test_size=0.3)
if y_train.shape[1] == 1:
   loss = 'binary_crossentropy'
else:
   loss = 'categorical_crossentropy'
```

When I do this, I get the error:

> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

My data is one-hot encoded. How can I resolve this error? Thanks

Comment: Shuffle your data simple!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I do shuffle my data in the train test split. Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: Any suggestion?

Comment: Well we will need a minimal reproducible example to help you further! But I feel error means something else :) (try checking it out!)